# C++ & RAPIDJSON: Smart "Dynamic nested loop" required

Tags: c++, json, nested-loops, rapidjson

I have two issues with the code:

1. The code crashes with assertion IsString() at line 82. I don't understand why since the value should be a string.
2. I need to have a smarter possibility of "dynamic" nested loops to go through the JSON data. Means: I would like to have the possibility to let the code decide - based on the objects found an the current level in the tree - to "spawn" a new loop for the objects, arrays and strings found on the deeper level. Since the JSON data is being pulled via CURL from a REST API in my main code I can not work with the pointers RAPIDJSON provides. The JSON data & structure pulled is not static and can change.

What the code should do: Go through the JSON string s and parse all Objects, Arrays and Strings and print them. The JSON data is nested and contains a "tree" which can have objects with furher objects underneath.
If you have a look at http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=d9425ccdb8614d9b1fb8bc24a74cbfb0 you can see the tree structure and that the JSON string is valid.

Required for the code to run: The include files from RAPIDJSON at github:
https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

// RAPIDJSON -> https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/
#include <rapidjson/document.h>
#include <rapidjson/reader.h>
#include <rapidjson/writer.h>

#include <typeinfo>

int main()
{
  // JSON String works -> http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=d9425ccdb8614d9b1fb8bc24a74cbfb0
  //
  // Types:
  // "" = string
  // [] = array
  // {} = object
  //
  std::string s = "{\"success\":1,\"data\":{\"species\":{\"rowcount\":6,\"totalrows\":\"6\",\"estimatedrows\":false,\"pagesize\":0,\"pagecount\":null,\"page\":1,\"offset\":0,\"startrow\":0,\"resultset\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Nuts\",\"code\":\"NUT\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"Cachew\",\"code\":\"CHEW\"},{\"id\":\"3\",\"name\":\"Coconut\",\"code\":\"COCO\"}]},\"affiliations\":{\"rowcount\":6,\"totalrows\":\"6\",\"estimatedrows\":false,\"pagesize\":0,\"pagecount\":null,\"page\":1,\"offset\":0,\"startrow\":0,\"resultset\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Ananas\",\"code\":\"NASS\",\"color\":\"#48bbd4\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"Kiwis\",\"code\":\"KIWI\",\"color\":\"#ffce17\"},{\"id\":\"3\",\"name\":\"Bananas\",\"code\":\"BANA\",\"color\":\"#bd002d\"}]}},\"code\":\"OK\",\"msg\":\"OK\"}";


  // Create document
  rapidjson::Document doc;

  // Check for parsing errors
  if (doc.Parse<0>(s.c_str()).HasParseError()) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to parse args: %s\n", s.c_str());

  } else {
    // Types
    static const char* kt[] = { "Null", "False", "True", "Object", "Array", "String", "Number" };
    // Loop through members
    for (rapidjson::Value::ConstMemberIterator itr = doc.MemberBegin(); itr != doc.MemberEnd(); ++itr) {
      fprintf(stderr, "member %s is a %s -> ", itr->name.GetString(), kt[itr->value.GetType()]);

      switch (itr->value.GetType()) {
      case rapidjson::kNullType: fprintf(stderr, "null"); break;
      case rapidjson::kFalseType: fprintf(stderr, "False"); break;
      case rapidjson::kTrueType: fprintf(stderr, "True"); break;
      case rapidjson::kObjectType: fprintf(stderr, "Object"); break;
      case rapidjson::kArrayType: fprintf(stderr, "size = %d", itr->value.Size()); break;
      case rapidjson::kStringType: fprintf(stderr, "%s", itr->value.GetString()); break;
      case rapidjson::kNumberType:
        if (itr->value.IsInt())
          fprintf(stderr, "%d", itr->value.GetInt());
        else
          fprintf(stderr, "%lf", itr->value.GetDouble());
        break;
      default: fprintf(stderr, "???"); break;
      }

      fprintf(stderr, "\n");

      // Loops to dive deeper into objects - Need a smarter solution for dynamic nested loops
      if (itr->value.GetType() == rapidjson::kObjectType) {
        fprintf(stderr, "parse %s\n", itr->name.GetString());
        for (rapidjson::Value::ConstMemberIterator itr2 = itr->value.MemberBegin(); itr2 != itr->value.MemberEnd(); ++itr2) {
          fprintf(stderr, "member %s:%s is a %s\n", itr->name.GetString(), itr2->name.GetString(), kt[itr2->value.GetType()]);
          if (itr2->value.GetType() == rapidjson::kObjectType) {
            for (rapidjson::Value::ConstMemberIterator itr3 = itr2->value.MemberBegin(); itr3 != itr2->value.MemberEnd(); ++itr3) {
              fprintf(stderr, "member %s:%s:%s is a %s\n", itr->name.GetString(), itr2->name.GetString(), itr3->name.GetString(), kt[itr3->value.GetType()]);

              switch (itr3->value.GetType()) {
              case rapidjson::kNullType: printf("%s=null\n", itr2->name.GetString()); break;
              case rapidjson::kFalseType: printf("%s=False\n", itr2->name.GetString()); break;
              case rapidjson::kTrueType: printf("%s=True\n", itr2->name.GetString()); break;
              case rapidjson::kStringType: printf("%s=%s\n", itr2->name.GetString(), itr3->name.GetString()); break;
              case rapidjson::kNumberType:
                if (itr3->value.IsInt())
                  printf("%s=%d\n", itr2->name.GetString(), itr3->value.GetInt());
                else
                  printf("%s=%lf\n", itr2->name.GetString(), itr3->value.GetDouble());
             break;

              case rapidjson::kArrayType:
                {
                  // Values are of type string in JSON! WTF?!?
                  printf("%s=", itr2->name.GetString());
                  rapidjson::Value::ConstValueIterator itr4 = itr3->value.Begin();
//////////////////
                    printf("%s", itr4->GetString());                                                         // BANG, BANG! She hits the ground..
                    for (++itr4; itr4 != itr3->value.End(); ++itr4) {
                    printf(",%s", itr4->GetString());                                                        // Obviously she hits the ground too!
                    }
//////////////////
                    printf("\n");

                }
                break;
              default: printf("???\n"); break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I am not an expert in C/C++ and currently lost with this situation. Any help to solve my 2 issues would be really appreciated.

I searched meanwhile for several days to get ideas to solve this without succes. The parsing examples found only handles "flat" JSON data without sub-objects.

Comment: It sounds like you need recursion to do what you want.

Comment: All the values in your JSON array have quotes around them which makes them strings.  Remove the quotes to treat as numbers.